# Python REST API Numeric Type Route Parameter Issues

Tags: python, flask, swagger, flask-restplus

I'm starting a new project in Python to aid me helping to learn the language.  I'm a C# developer and very comfortable with REST APIs, but I feel I'm missing something in Python.  I am writing this with Flask-RESTPlus and have been following examples to get it working.  As it currently stands, I do have a working API, but I'm trying to figure this one last piece out.

I need to be able to create an API endpoint that accepts a numeric route parameter, regardless of whether it's an int of a float.

I can get my API working properly if I add multiple routes, but there has to be a better way.

One of my endpoints:

```py
ns_area = Namespace('Area', description='Area calculations')
@ns_area.route('/Acre/<float:input>/ToSquareFoot')
class ConversionsArea(Resource):
    def get(self, input):
        input = float(input)
        return area.acre_to_ft2(input)
```

This returns a proper calculation

```
curl -X GET "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/Area/Acre/1.2/ToSquareFoot" -H "accept: application/json"
```

This returns a 404 because the route parameter isn't a floating point number

```
curl -X GET "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/Area/Acre/1/ToSquareFoot" -H "accept: application/json"
```

Also, if I don't have a type identifier, it defaults to a string.

I'd really rather not have to duplicate routes like this.

```py
ns_area = Namespace('Area', description='Area calculations')
@ns_area.route('/Acre/<float:input>/ToSquareFoot')
@ns_area.route('/Acre/<int:input>/ToSquareFoot')
class ConversionsArea(Resource):
    def get(self, input):
        input = float(input)
        return area.acre_to_ft2(input)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `string` in path and evaluate can it be converted to `float`. If not, raise `ValueError` and print proper message.

```
ns_area = Namespace('Area', description='Area calculations')
@ns_area.route('/Acre/<string:input>/ToSquareFoot')
class ConversionsArea(Resource):
    def get(self, input):
        try:
            input = float(input)
            return area.acre_to_ft2(input), 200
        except ValueError:
            return "Can't convert {} to number".format(input), 400
```

Comment: Thank you!  This looks like exactly what I need.  I'll get this implemented